# Fast Report 5 VCL Issue during export to Word "Docx". "µg/kg" is being exported as "Âµg/kg"

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Fast Report 5 VCL  Issue during export to Word "Docx"   µg/kg is being exported as Âµg/kg.

Using Fast Report  Version VCL 5.6.17 with Delphi 7.

How to Reproduce the Error.

1. Create  a new page.
2. In the Report Title Band , put 1 Memo (TfrxMemoView)
3. In the memo Text, put  "µg/kg" as text.
4. Use the Export to Microsoft Word 2007 XML.

On the Exported Word Document  "µg/kg" is shown as Âµg/kg. 
In the Exported Word document an extra character "Â" is injected.

Similarly some of the other characters like  "δβγδεζ" etc have also the same issue.

Can someone guide me as to what all i can try to resolve the problem. 
I have tried with various font combinations to resolve this issue and am running out of ideas.

Direct printing as well export to PDF does not have any issue.

I have Reported this problem to Fast Report. So hopefully they should help me out.

Thanks

Comment: We can have no clue about. this. Imagine *you* were presented with this question. How would you even begin to go about answering it?

Comment: Try https://www.fast-report.com/en/support/

Comment: It exports fine with me (also latest FR version) , check Your encoding

Comment: Fast Report Support  has given  me the support  to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast Report Team has given me the new Pas file which has resolved the issue.
Thanks